# Firefox font not displaying correctly

Tags: firefox, fonts

Here's a comparison for what it looks like in Chrome, Safari, then Firefox:

[image: Chrome, Safari, Firefox]

I tried adding weights to it but didn't change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using custom fonts? Are the custom fonts in the same location as the css files? For chrome you can use text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;

Comment: Also  rearranging the @font-face CSS rule to allow svg's to appear 'first' fixes many custom font issues. Play with optimizeLegibility: http://aestheticallyloyal.com/public/optimize-legibility/

And also -webkit-font-smoothing: http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing

Comment: I'm using the 'Lato' family from Google Fonts. @Himu